# What can lead to the DatabaseError: Request has timed out while writing with firebase realtime database android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing to the firebase realtime database with android sdk and after long time I am starting to receive `DatabaseError: Request has timed`. I have noticed that it also depends on amount of write requests. To force this error I should increase amount of write requests. In the same time I sure that I am not reaching caping in amount of data that I am trying to write either with Mb or times per sec. My application designed to do some work in the foreground and background (last one by using work manager) and in order to fix this issue I should restart application from icon, then writes becomes ok.

Full error looks like `updateChildren at /mypath/authId failed: DatabaseError: Request has timed out`. Any idea what can lead with this exception or how should I handle it?

There are some additional context, I am using code to initialise firebase sdk instead of .json file like the following with application class so I am sure sdk suppose to be alive:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(
   getAppContext(), FirebaseOptions.Builder()
      .setApplicationId(getAppContext().getString(R.string.firebase_app_id))
      .setProjectId(getAppContext().getString(R.string.firebase_project_id))
      .setApiKey(getAppContext().getString(R.string.firebase_app_key))
      .build(), getAppContext().getString(R.string.firebase_app_name))
```

Then I am using anonymous authentication in order to get authId that I have mentioned as part of path for writing. There is a firebase rule in order to allow writing only for authenticated users. I also have implement some mechanism for re-authentication if agent somehow lost the current one (it happens with anonymous authentication) so this is not suppose to be related with wrong authId.

This is the method for writing data

```
fun write(log: BaseLog, onComplete: (() -> Unit)? = null) {
    FirebaseUtil.requireUid().continueWith { uidTask ->
        getRef(log.getPath(), "${dailyKey()}/${uidTask.result}")
            .updateChildren(log.toMap())
            .continueWithTask {
                getRef(userLog.getPath(), uidTask.result).updateChildren(UserLog().toMap())
            }.addOnCompleteListener {
               onComplete?.invoke()
            }
    }
}
```

Last thing I have done - I am caching database references that I am writing with hash map like that

```
fun getRef(path: String, res: String): DatabaseReference {
    val fullPath = "${fullPath(path)}/$res" // fullPath another one function that returns path as string, nothing special

    return if(databaseRefs[fullPath] != null) {
        // databaseRefs - just HashMap<String, DatabaseReference>
        databaseRefs[fullPath]!!
    } else {
        val ref = database.getReference(fullPath)
        databaseRefs[fullPath] = ref
        ref
    }
}
```

Ok I believe that I have mentioned enough for your context, fell free to ask any details - I will gladly share with you.